# setAttribute("value") not working on password field

Tags: javascript

Sometimes passwordField.setAttribute("value","newValue") doesn't work on my password field. But passwordField.value = "newValue" always works.

moreover, setAttribute is working fine on Mac platform but sometimes doesn't work on win platform

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about attributes for HTML elements in JavaScript. There are issues in IE, they don't do exactly what you think and are unnecessarily verbose. The `value` property does exactly what you need and works correctly in all scriptable browsers.

```
var input = document.getElementById("your_input");
input.value = "blah";
```

Answer (score 0):

`.setAttribute()` does not work in Internet Explorer. I suggest using a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for DOM-manipulation, since it works cross-browser. This is the jQuery-way of doing this:

```
$(passwordField).val('newValue');
```

Take a look at the [getting started guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).

Comment: jQuery is overkill for this when the `value` property works perfectly.

Comment: Thats right, but since jQuery fixes a lot of DOM-related compatibility problems, this might be useful anyway. `getElementById()` is about the only DOM-method that is cross-browser. This is a mess without normalization.